# PowerBI - Importing specific sheets from multiple Excel files in SharePoint folder

Tags: powerbi

I have a collection of Excel documents stored in SharePoint. The documents have an identical format (they have the same sheets and each sheet have the same columns). Now I want to import a specific sheet from each of the Excel files in the SharePoint folder.

I have created a function:

```
   let GetExcel  = (FileName, FolderPath) =>
    let
        Source = SharePoint.Files(FolderPath, [ApiVersion = 15]),
        TheFile = Source{[Name=FileName,#"Folder Path"=FolderPath]}[Content],
        #"Imported Excel" = Excel.Workbook(TheFile),
        #"Särskilt boende_Sheet" = #"Imported Excel"{[Item="Särskilt boende",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Särskilt boende_Sheet")
    in
        #"Promoted Headers"
    in GetExcel
```

I have the added a custom column, like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each GetExcel([Name], [Folder Path]))
```

When I try to load the report I get the following error:

```
    An error occurred in the ‘GetExcel’ query. DataSource.Error:
 Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed: 
    OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
    OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
    OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)
    Details:
        DataSourceKind=SharePoint
        DataSourcePath=<Here is a path to our shared folder in SharePoint>
```

I have tried to find out what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get my head around this. Do you have any ideas to what I'm doing wrong, please help :)

Kind regards,
Peter Rundqvist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what values you're sending your function, but I tried running it step-by-step and I think you've misunderstood what arguments the functions are expecting. `FolderPath` needs to be trimmed for your first line

```
Source = SharePoint.Files(FolderPath, [ApiVersion = 15])
```

`FolderPath` here should be the root of the sharepoint site or sub-site hosting the file you want. `SharePoint.Files` returns a table of all the files on the site.

```
TheFile = Source{[Name=FileName,#"Folder Path"=FolderPath]}[Content]
```

`FolderPath` here is the 'path' through the sharepoint folders to the file, formatted like a url.

Together, they should look like this.

```
Source = SharePoint.Files("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/thesite", [ApiVersion = 15]),
TheFile = Source{[Name="Workbook.xlsx",#"Folder Path"="https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/thesite/Reports/2016/November/Finance Committee/"]}[Content]
```

Good luck!

d